# Mysql update using values from select

Tags: mysql

I have two queries. The first will return multiple rows:

```
SELECT parent_entry_id,child_entry_id FROM exp_playa_relationships WHERE parent_field_id = '34';
```

...And I would like to use the values (parent_entry_id,child_entry_id) and incorporate them into this query, replacing 'x' and 'y', and do it for each row returned by the first query.

```
UPDATE exp_channel_data AS t1,
(
SELECT field_id_46,field_id_47 FROM exp_channel_data WHERE entry_id = 'x') AS t2
SET t1.field_id_60 = t2.field_id_46, t1.field_id_61 = t2.field_id_47
WHERE t1.entry_id = 'y';
```

I think I need to use another JOIN, but I can't figure out how to implement one in my example. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your replies. The working syntax is:

```
UPDATE exp_channel_data AS t1,
(
SELECT 
entry_id as ei2, child_entry_id, parent_entry_id, field_id_46 as f46,field_id_47 as f47 
FROM 
exp_channel_data JOIN exp_playa_relationships ON entry_id=child_entry_id AND parent_field_id = 34) AS t2
SET t1.field_id_60 = f46, t1.field_id_61 = f47
WHERE t1.entry_id=parent_entry_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
UPDATE exp_channel_data a1 INNER JOIN exp_playa_relationships a  ON a1.entry_id = a.child_entry_id
INNER JOIN exp_channel_data b ON a.parent_entry_id = b.entri_id 
SET a1.field_id_60 = b.field_id_46, ta1.field_id_61 = b.field_id_47
WHERE parent_field_id = '34'
```

Comment: @eggyal can you let me know which syntax?

Comment: yes that is valid in sql server, i updated to mysql version thanks for noting that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, rs, though has also not updated the data in exp_channel_data.

Comment: run this query and can you post results? `SELECT a1.field_id_60, b.field_id_46, a1.field_id_61, b.field_id_47
FROM exp_channel_data a1 INNER JOIN exp_playa_relationships a  ON a1.entry_id = a.child_entry_id
INNER JOIN exp_channel_data b ON a.parent_entry_id = b.entri_id 
WHERE parent_field_id = '34'`

Comment: That returns the expected number of rows, but no values for any of the fields. There should at least be data for field_id_46, field_id_47. Thanks *edit to correct field ids

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after:

```
UPDATE exp_playa_relationships AS t0
  JOIN exp_channel_data        AS t1
    ON t1.entry_id = t0.child_entry_id
  JOIN exp_channel_data        AS t2
    ON t2.entry_id = t0.parent_entry_id
   SET t1.field_id_60 = t2.field_id_46
     , t1.field_id_61 = t2.field_id_47
```

Comment: Ok, it's exp_channel_data I want to UPDATE, not exp_playa_relationships. Guess this will work but I would need to swap a few bits around? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @user1368392: You don't need to swap anything around... the tables are joined just like with a `SELECT` statement, then the ones you are updating appear under `SET ...`.  The fact it reads in English as though you're updating `exp_playa_relationships` is unfortunate, but is not true.

Comment: Ok, I will take a closer look as running the statement as it stands has not updated the data.

Comment: @user1368392: Check that I have the join conditions right... wasn't 100% clear from your question which is child and which is parent.

Answer (score -1):

Or in a more classic syntax, you need to adjust to your own foo & bar attributes, but use something like the following:

```
update exp_channel_data t1
set (t1.field_id_60,t1.field_id_61) = (
    select t2.field_id_46 , t2.field_id_47
    from exp_channel_data t2
    where 1=1
      and t2.entry_id = 'x'
      and /* ENTER YOUR t1-t2 join condition here */
)
where 1=1
  and t1.entry_id = y
;
```

But since you are MySQL I don't believe it supports compound subquery.  As such:

```
update exp_channel_data t1
set t1.field_id_60 = (
    select t2.field_id_46 
    from exp_channel_data t2
    where 1=1
      and t2.entry_id = 'x'
      and /* ENTER YOUR t1-t2 join condition here */
) , t1.field_id_61 = (
    select t3.field_id_47
    from exp_channel_data t3
    where 1=1
      and t3.entry_id = 'x'
      and /* ENTER YOUR t1-t3 join condition here */
)
where 1=1
  and t1.entry_id = y
;
```

Comment: From the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/update.html): "*Currently, you cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery.*"

Comment: Go MySQL!!!  Apparently, we need to create lovely temp tables.  That syntax not worth it :(

Comment: Not necessary.  One can use the multiple-table `UPDATE` syntax per my answer.

Comment: @eggyal, correct, but to support the subselect update, one would need to do that...